# Gradle build error: cannot access ParametersAreNonnullByDefault class file when using Realm

Tags: android, gradle, realm

I'm writing an Android library project in which I have a dependency on Realm. For some reason when I add Realm as a dependency in my Gradle files, I get a build error. Specifically:

```
Error:cannot access ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
class file for javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault not found
```

I'm just following the Get Started on the Realm website.

My project level build.gradle looks like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My application level gradle.build looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'

    //Puree
    compile 'com.cookpad.puree:puree:4.1.1'

    //Square
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:tape:1.2.3'
}
```

I have no idea what is going wrong. At first I thought it might be some conflict between the other dependencies, but I created a new project adding the same dependencies one by one and I had no compilation problems.

Comment: I am able to build project. with exactly same config.
Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Yep, cleaned and built it several times. No luck :(

Comment: are you obfuscating your app?

Comment: minifyEnabled is false

Comment: can you add the stacktrace? `./gradlew build --stacktrace`

Comment: What is your JDK version?

Comment: My JDK version is 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the following dependency:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9' //try also provided
```

Comment: For some strange reason, it works when adding this dependency. Can you explain why? Thx for the answer!

Comment: I'll be honest: I have no idea. Does it work only with `compile`, or it also works with `provided` instead of `compile`?

Comment: Good, at least that means you don't have to add anything extra :)   I have no idea what broke on your end though. This isn't a dependency for Realm afaik